# $\overline M = M$ (closure of $M$ is $M$)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have an intuition that an entire metric space (not a subset of it) does not have boundaries, so its closure would be itself, but how to prove it?

Comment: What is your definition of the closure?

Comment: The closure of a subset $A\subset M$ is the smallest closed set of $M$ that contains $A$. What does this give for $A=M$ ?

Comment: the definition is the one of the adherent points

Comment: What do you call an "entire metric space"?

Comment: Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. For all subsets of $A\subseteq X$, it holds $A\subseteq \overline A\subseteq X$. If we set $A=X$, we get $X\subseteq \overline X\subseteq X$, whence $\overline X=X$.

Comment: There is the notion of the _completion_ of a metric space $M$, which in a sense is what the closure of $M$ would look like if it were a subset of a bigger space.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli my book says: $F\subset M \iff$ $M-F$ is open, but it does not say that $A\subseteq X \implies \overline{A}\subseteq X$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli can I say that $M\subset M\implies M-M = \emptyset$ is open, therefore, I can assume what you said?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Anything is contained in the ambient space. The closure of something in a topological space $(X,\tau)$ is the (bla bla bla 1) **subset of $X$** such that (bla bla bla 2). Which makes the closure a non-intrinsic definition. For instance, the closure $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb Q$ is $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Does my answer satisfy you? If not, could you clarify what you don't understand about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I gather from your comments that you define the closure $\overline{A}$ of a set $A\subseteq M$ to be the set of all points in $M$ which are adherent points of $A$. I assume your definition of adherent point agrees with the one [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adherent_point).

Note that for any set $A\subseteq M$, $\overline{A}\subseteq M$, by definition.

Also, for any set $A\subseteq M$, $A\subseteq \overline{A}$. Proof: Let $x\in A$. For every open set $U$ containing $x$, $U$ contains a point of $A$ (namely $x$). So $x$ is an adherent point of $A$, and $x\in \overline{A}$.

Taking $A = M$, $\overline{M}\subseteq M$ and $M\subseteq \overline{M}$, so $M = \overline{M}$.

Answer (score 4):

We know that the distance of a point $x$ to a set $A$ is $d(x,A)=\inf_{y\in A}d(x,y)$. Now using your definition, $$\overline{M}=\{x\in M\,|\,d(x,M)=0\}$$ So clearly, $\overline M\subseteq M$.

If $x\in M$ then $d(x,M)=0$, thus $x\in \overline M$.

So $M=\overline M$

Answer (score 4):

Let $M$ be any metric space, let $S$ be any subset of $M$ (possibly $M$ itself), let $x \in M$.

Definition 1: We say that $x$ is an **adherent point** of $S$ if for any open set $V$ of $M$ with $x \in S$, the intersection $S \cap V$ is nonempty.

Definition 2:  The **closure** of $S$ in $M$, denoted $\overline{S}$, is the set of adherent points of $S$.

We always have $\overline{S} \subseteq M$.  This is clear, because points of $\overline{S}$ are defined to be certain points of $M$.

Lemma: For any subset $S$ of $M$, $S \subseteq \overline{S}$.

Proof: Let $x \in S$.  We want to show that $x$ is an adherent point of $S$.  Let $V$ be any open subset of $M$ with $x \in V$.  We need to argue that the intersection $S \cap V$ is nonempty.  But this is clear, because $x$ is in this intersection.  $\blacksquare$

Now let $S = M$.  We want to show that $\overline{M}$ is equal to $M$.  By the remark after Definition 2, we know that $\overline{M} \subseteq M$.  But on the other hand, the Lemma tells us that $M \subseteq \overline{M}$.  So $M = \overline{M}$.

Comment: This is almost exactly the same as the answer I posted yesterday...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the other answers before I wrote this.  Gave you an upvote tho :P

Comment: No problem, and thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Observe that given any topology $T$ on $M$ , $\emptyset$ and the whole space $M$ always lie in $T$. This  just follows from the definition of topology.

Now since sets in $T$ are defined to be $open$ $sets$ and complement of open sets are $closed$, the proof follows.

Comment: Yes! i will make the edit

Answer (score 3):

$\overline{M}$ by your definition is a closed set of $M$, so $\overline{M} \subseteq M$.  At the same time, any subset $E$ of $M$ is contained in its closure $\overline{E}$.  So $M \subseteq \overline{M}$.  Hence $M = \overline{M}$.

Comment: I didn't define $\overline{M}$ as being a closed set, I did define it in relation to the adherent points.

Comment: Okay, I will write a new answer with more detail.

Answer (score 2):

For $M\subset\overline{M}$:
$\forall x\in M$, $\forall B$ an open ball containing $x$, we have $x\in B\cap M$, then $B\cap M\ne\emptyset$. By the definition of "closure", we obtain that $x\in\overline{M}$. Thus $M\subset\overline{M}$.

For $\overline{M}\subset M$:
$\forall x\in\overline{M}$, by the definition of "closure", we konw that $\exists B_x$ the open ball containing $x$, such that $B_x\cap M\ne\emptyset$. Since $B_x$ is an open ball with respect to the entire metric space $M$, it is thereby a relatively open set in $M$, which implies $B_x\subset M$. By recalling $x\in B_x$, we have $x\in M$. Hence $\overline{M}\subset M$.

We are done.